# Background-image not showing when border-image is applied in Safari and Opera

Tags: firefox, safari, background-image, opera, css

I am applying the following CSS classes to my site footer, to display both a background image to it, and a 3px 3-tone border along the top.

```
.site-footer {
    background-image: url(../img/footer-background.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-width: 3px 0px 0px;
    padding: 15px 0;
}

.border-image {
    -webkit-border-image: url(../img/footer-border-hr.png) 2 0 0 0 repeat;
       -moz-border-image: url(../img/footer-border-hr.png) 2 0 0 0 repeat;
         -o-border-image: url(../img/footer-border-hr.png) 2 0 0 0 repeat;
            border-image: url(../img/footer-border-hr.png) 2 0 0 0 repeat;
            border-width: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

It is fine in Chrome (18), but the background is just plain white in, Firefox (Mac 10.0.2 and 11) Safari (Mac Version 5.1.5 (7534.55.3)) and Opera (Mac 11.62). Removing the border-image via inspect element reinstates the background.
I am guessing that border-images are basically rendered as background-images and therefore the background is being overridden, but does anybody know a work around?

Comment: Can you link to an actual page showing the problem?

Comment: I'd love to, but I think my bosses wouldn't be happy with that. Sorry this is unhelpful. I shall try and upload a test case of some kind later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing a white background because presumably the center piece of your border image is white, it is drawn on top of the background image, and most browsers implemented an experimental version of `border-image` before the addition of [the `fill` keyword](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-image-slice).

As the spec describes:

> The ‘fill’ keyword, if present, causes the middle part of the border-image to be preserved. (By default it is discarded, i.e., treated as empty.)

Browsers that don't support this fill keyword (I know at least Opera and Firefox don't, though [Firefox will support it as of version 12](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-border-image#border-image-width)) do not discard the middle of the border-image, but draw it on top of the background.

Since you're using PNGs, you can make sure that the middle piece of your border-image is transparent. That should make the background appear through it.